# Displaying a list of views

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Here's a mockup:

[A mockup http://img.skitch.com/20090228-mqdj17xijycc98spf181a8q6q7.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090228-mqdj17xijycc98spf181a8q6q7.jpg)

I have been trying to find some sample code that showcases something like this -- a scroll view with a list of custom views. Haven't found anything. I've been trying to find some open source projects that does this (that isn't Adium with a million files and lines of code), but haven't found anything there either.

I've been told that I can use NSMatrix to achieve this. Again, haven't found any sample code.

Anyone got some suggestions? Or sample code ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use `NSTableView` and create a custom subclass of `NSCell` to render the content.

Answer (score 2):

If you can require Leopard, take a look at [NSCollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSCollectionView_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html). The API is a little weird but it's pretty powerful once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been told that I can use NSMatrix to achieve this.

You can't. NSMatrix uses cells, not views.

To answer your question: What James Williams said.